# Getting Network Error when trying to send Image to pre-signed URL in React Native

Tags: react-native, axios, form-data

In my react native project I need to be able to send Images using axios to an API. For that I have the following function:

```
    export function SetImage(image, id, token)
    {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file',{
        uri: image.uri,
        type: image.type,
        })

        return axios({
            method: 'PUT',
            url: axios.defaults.baseURL + "/api/SetImage/"+ID,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' ,
                'Authorization': 'Bearer: '+token,
            },
            data: formData
        })
    }
```

Image is the return Object I got from [`ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync`](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/) function which looks something like this:

```
    {
       "cancelled": false,
       "height": 2048,
       "type": "image",
       "uri": "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/<PathtoSomewhere>/ImagePicker/1d408e33-b54a-4189- 
       ac66-bd86ec11069a.jpg",
       "width": 946,
      }
```

However when I try to use the function I get the following error, that doesn't tell me anything:

```
    Network Error
    at node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:14 in createError
    at node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\xhr.js:84:13 in handleError
    - ... 9 more stack frames from framework internals
```

Comment: Have you tried to upload an image in a REST client (such as [Postman](https://www.postman.com/), [Insomnia](https://www.insomnia.rest/), etc) and make sure everything works?

Comment: yes I have tested it in Postman and it works there

Answer (score 0):

I recently have to add same functionality to my project (upload image trough a pre-signed URL). This one is the ones that works for me:

```
const uploadImage = async ({ method, url, file }: any) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', file.type);
        xhr.onload = () => {
            if (xhr.status !== 200) {
                reject(
                    new Error(
                        `Request failed. Status: ${xhr.status}. Content: ${xhr.responseText
                        }`,
                    ),
                );
            }
            resolve(xhr.responseText);
        };
        xhr.send(file);
    });
};

// image === image inside local phone
export const uploadImageToUrl = async ({ image, url }: any) => {
    await uploadImage({
        method: 'PUT', url, file: {
            uri: image.uri,
            type: image.type,
        }
    });

    return { url };
};
```

To upload an image, you just need to call it like:

```
uploadImageToUrl({ url: your-upload-url, image: your-image-object-from-image-picker })
```

*Note: pass the whole image object to the function (not just the uri)*

Also add this line if necessary:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + jwtoken);
```